# Inserting BLOB using OData and Oracle

Tags: oracle, entity-framework, blob, odata, dbcontext

When working with OData and Oracle i need to insert blob records in some table.
I tried to follow example here : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astoriateam/archive/2010/08/04/data-services-streaming-provider-series-implementing-a-streaming-provider-part-1.aspx
As microsoft recomend i exclude my BLOB from data model.
At the end, data is sent to my service, in GetWriteStream() i write binary data to temporary file. Then in Dispose() i should insert it in database.
But...
Using DbContext, i cant do this :
ObjectStateEntry entry = 
            this.context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(cachedEntity);

converting this.context to dbcontext throw exception - DbContext cant be used because its disposed. 
I still cant understand how to do this?
I didnt find any example in the internet where is described how to use OData with blobs and dbcontext to work with database directly.

Using : WCF Data Services 5.1.0-rc2, Visual Studio 2012, Oracle 11.x with ODP